# How can I add a link in my credits.rtf file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm building an Xcode application and would like to add a link to a website in my credits.rtf file.  How would I do this?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Insert a line corresponding to the URL of your link, or add a link to some already existing text of your file?

Comment: The question in kind confusing. Maybe you are looking for the syntax that creates a link on a .rtf file? Like this: `{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"}{\fldrslt http://www.stackoverflow.com}}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- In Xcode right click on the `Credits.rtf` file.
- Select **Open As**
- Select **Source Code**
- Add the following to create a link `{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://google.com"}}{\fldrslt Google}}`

Answer (score 4):

Open Credits.rtf in Xcode, select the text you want to be a link, and choose the **Editor > Add Link...** menu item to turn it into a link.